# How to use Post method in def create action in ruby on rails for fetching data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, post

I want to fetch data from client side to ruby on rails by using post method in create action in my controller.But i dont know how to do for getting data from client side in def create action.How to create the api for to get data from client side.

Postcontroller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
respond_to :json, :xml

  before_filter :load

  def load
    if signed_in?
      @my_posts = current_user.posts.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 10)
      @my_post = current_user.posts.new
    end
    @posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 10)
    @post = Post.new
  end


  def index
    @posts = Post.all
    respond_with(@posts) do |format|
      format.json { render json: @post_names = {:post => @posts.as_json(:only=> :content)} }
    end
  end 

  def show
    if signed_in?
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
      @my_posts = current_user.posts.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 10)
      current_user.vote_for(@post)
    else
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    Guest.find(1).vote_for(@post)
    end
    @posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 10)  
    @guest = Guest.new
    @user = User.new
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 10)
  end

  def create 
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])
     respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save
      @posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 10)
      format.json { render json: @post, status: :created }

    else 
      @posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 10)
      format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }

    end
    @guest = Guest.new
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 10)
 end
  end

  def my_prayer_create     
      @my_post = current_user.posts.new(params[:post])
      @post = Post.new(params[:post])
      @guest = Guest.new
      @user = User.new
      @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 10)
      if @my_post.save
        flash[:notice] = "Prayer Successfully created."
        @my_posts = current_user.posts.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 10)
      else 
        flash[:notice] = "Error"
        @my_posts = current_user.posts.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 10)
      end
  end

  def edit
    if signed_in?    
    @my_post = current_user.posts.find(params[:id])
    else
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end
  end

  def update
    if signed_in? 
      @my_post = current_user.posts.find(params[:id])
      if @my_post.update_attributes(params[:post])
        flash[:notice] = "Prayer Successfully updated."
        @my_posts = current_user.posts.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 10)
      end
    else  
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end
  end

  def destroy
    if signed_in? 
      @my_post = current_user.posts.find(params[:id])
      @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 10)
      @guest = Guest.new
      @my_post.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "Prayer Successfully destroyed."
      @my_posts = current_user.posts.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 10)
    end
  end
```

For my controller how can i fetch data from client side.from this only i have to write the url in my client side also like this `"http://localhost:3000/posts"`

Comment: why are you facing this in create action if save fails?

`@posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 10)`
while you return this:
      format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
`

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a method called `new`

Get all the user inputs in new method and pass it to create method.

new method:

```
def new
    @post = Post.new
 end
```

create method:

```
@post = Post.new(params[:post])
```

params[:post] pass all params  and save it by  `@post.save`.

Read rails doc for CURD operations first.

EDIT:

in routes.rb:

```
match '/action' => "controller#action"
```

write view file for new method to get use input in `"views/controller/new.html.erb"`

Comment: i want to create an new action am i correct mam,what are the thing has to be in new method and what are the things want to pass to create method?

Comment: I used get method to pass data using json from ror to android,but now i want to be vice versa method,if i add any data in android it has to be go to ror server side.for that i want to give an url also in android side also

Comment: can you please edit your answer what code i have to write,it will be very helpful

Comment: read this if you are new to ROR.http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html. You want to pass those params to your method (ror)   and do action what ever you want

Comment: ,Can you look at my code and edit your answer and give the solution for me,to solve this issue,i want only post method to get the data from client side,i am android developer but these part i want to do in server side,thats why can you help me

Comment: Durga Ganesh,i think you are also tamil,so i tell in tamil that might be better to communicate.enaku get method use pani ror to android anupitaen ipa post method use pani epadi android to ror anupa thaeriyalam,konjam help panringala,answer edit pani epadinu sollunga

Comment: @ Karthick M - Cool. I dont know android.But i am sure you just pass your mobile params as  @post = Post.new(your params).It will save in DB.

Comment: no nenga android side help pana vaynam,enaku ror server sidela tan doubt,nan android(client side) athula irunthu data anupuna epadi rorla get panalam athavathu post method in create action

Comment: ,how to do that one for fetching data from client side

Comment: ,are u there?cant get the solutn

Comment: Not getting any correct solution,have u findout how to overcome this problem

Comment: sorry.I Dont.You just tag your question as android.You may get solution from experts

Comment: no @Durga Ganesh,i dont want from android,my android part is very clear,i want only from ror side

Comment: I need only ror side how to use post method to get data from client side,we have to write in create action,thats the thing i want only ror side sis

Comment: You will pass your user inputs as params to some methods no..Can you show those codes? Then it may give clear idea of your problem.

Comment: @Karthick M are you got my point? you will get user inputs as array brackets in android right. show those params also when you click submit or what ever it may be button,where you passing those params.Show that code also.I will try to give solution.Actually you are trying for simple solutions.

Comment: ,ya i got your point,now its fetching i changed some minor its working but ,whatever i am typing its not fetching there,its shows only the content as null,might be the params problem i will show you both server and client side code

Comment: here is the link i post server and cient side code  http://pastebin.com/0JUi7fvQ  there i put changed server side code also,it showing only null,not what i am giving in android its not showing

Comment: ,irukingala, code pathingala,nan kudukura content vara vayrum nullnu taniruku

Comment: dude.cool.check your terminal or log.you will pass params from user input to create method.copy those params and post here.I want to see those params only

Comment: http://pastebin.com/0JUi7fvQ see here i post my code there,kindly check and tell ,which params,in db table title and content only is there,for that i want to send only content alone from android to server @Durga ganesh

Comment: if you are receiving params as  Parameters: {"content"=>"welcome","title"=>"check"} then you should write   @post = Post.create(:content=>params[:content],:title=>params[:title])

Comment: you are not getting what i am asking.Ok leave. remove the comment('#') #@post = Post.create(:content=>params[:post][":content"],:title=>params[:post][":title"]) in this line.Then put the code like this     @post = Post.create(:content=>params[:post][:content],:title=>params[:post][:title])

Comment: client side code is ok na,ony i want to change as serve side only na,i am sending only content so i have to write like this @post = Post.create(:content=>params[:content]) am i correct

Comment: I dont get your client side code.bacaz i am zero in androi.your server side code has some mistakes. put it like this.And pls let me know only results. no other comments pls. @post = Post.create(:content=>params[:post][:content],:title=>params[:post][:title])

Comment: ,eventhough that null also not coming

Comment: def create
     @post = Post.create(:content=>params[:post][:content],:title=>params[:post][:title])
     respond_to do |format|

Comment: remove this line  @post = Post.create(params[:content]). you have created it multiple times.

Comment: http://dry-brushlands-3645.herokuapp.com/ see this is link of my website,after 10.35 its not fetching that null also,i do what you told ,i removed that line and i paste your code,not working@Durga Ganesh

Comment: ok.In create method put (raise params.inspect) It will inspect your incoming params.Shows those code now

Comment: (raise params.inspect),this is the only line i want to put,and where i want to put that line

Comment: After def create.This is not solution. It will show your incoming params format.you should write code according to params format.then the prob get solve

Comment: actually now its not adding anything eventhough that null is also not working @Durga Ganesh,its not showing anything in cmd

Comment: are you sure you are getting something in params[:content].if yes try this @post = Post.new @post.content=params[:content] this will save your content in table

Comment: mostly params will pass as params[:table_name][:col_name].You could not solve this until you know the format of incoming params

Comment: if i am using this code only,it will gives the null now u check this link now i add one thing use that line of code http://dry-brushlands-3645.herokuapp.com/ @post = Post.create(params[:post])

Comment: if i use @post = Post.create(params[:post]) this line only it fetches but it showing null,can you got my point what i am getting,you can see this link what i am getting http://dry-brushlands-3645.herokuapp.com/

Comment: I got your point already.I am very much sure your server side code is perfect.You are doing mistake in naming params  Post.create(params[:post]). if server doesnt receive params[:post] then it will take as null values.Again repeating have look at the format of parameters you are getting.Means params[:post] or params[:posts] are any other naming

Comment: ,some params problem now,then i have to give proper params it should be same in server and client side also,ok if i give the param name as content how it will save the row in content,for this how to give the code to fetch the content data

Comment: params[:posts] i used this one also,this also giving null value only   http://mobiledevtuts.com/android/android-http-with-asynctask-example/ you see this link,there they are metion as httppost as "myhttpdata" and their server side also they are metion same in post

Comment: its working now,you also tell correct single problem in client side code also now got it thanks

Comment: actually thats not an correct answer you can change your answer,thats why i increase in your comment

Answer (score 0):

it seems if post saved successfully you will get created post. but if save fails then you are facing some posts

```
   @posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 10)
```

but responding using :

```
format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
```

So if you want to get some posts if post save fails then  it has to respond_with @posts

Answer (score 0):

I got solution for my question,what to use correct params in def create action

```
def create

  @post = Post.create(params[:post])
   #@post = Post.create(:content=>params[:post][":content"],:title=>params[:post][":title"])
   respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save
      @posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 10)
      format.json { render json: @post, status: :created }

    else
      @posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 10)
      format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }

    end
    @guest = Guest.new
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page],:per_page => 10)
 end
  end
```

the params should be same as like the client side given parameter also.

Answer (score 0):

To be precise and exact .. thats the style the normal ruby on rails crud operations follow.

let me be clear..

If you want to create a record in table USERS lets say fields are "name" and "age"
the params in the client side need not be same as the fields of the table.

In the above case we have handle the saving in controller,framework don't take of it.
say on client side 'x' for name and 'y' for age 
then the params built in the client side and passed to server is say params=>{:post=>{:x=>"siva", :y => "23"}}

In the controller.
    user=User.new
    user.name=params[:post][:x]
    user.age=params[:post][:y]
    user.save